# Can I 'frame' a web-app in an iPhone app

Tags: web-applications, iphone

I have a web app (HTML/JS/CSS) and would like to distribute it via the App store to iPhone users.

Am I able, from an App Store rules standpoint, to create a basic app which has a UIWebView (or via other method) which points at my web-app. The web-app would then load over the web each time the app is opened.

If not, am I able to do similar but load the 'web-app' from local HTML/JS/CSS files in the native app?

Comment: You know people can add a web app to their home screen from within Safari, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 6):

No, this application will be rejected.

From App Store Guidelines:

**Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be
    rejected**

Here is the [link](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf)

Comment: Thank god. Less crap in the app store. :D

Comment: @Radek S  agree. That's why I like iPhone more then Android: strict face-control =)

Comment: Thanks. The guidelines actually say that it _may_ be rejected. Do you have basis other than this part of the guidelines to state that it _will_ be rejected?

Comment: Yep. My experience of submitting 12 applications. Every day reviewers become even more strict.

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but no answer has mentioned [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) a.k.a. [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) which I believe may be interesting for anyone who finds this question.

Essentially it's a software that lets you write mobile applications for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada and Symbian in HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Quoting [PhoneGap article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap):

> It enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3, instead of device specific languages such as Objective-C. The resulting applications are hybrid, meaning that they are neither truly native (because all layout rendering is done via web views instead of the platform's native UI framework) nor purely web-based (because they are not just web apps, but are packaged as apps for distribution and have access to native device APIs).

There's a lot of useful info on the [Getting Started Guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html).

Answer (score 1):

http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/

You can try this link, it has really good details on how to convert any web app to an apple-looking format with different libraries such as jqtouch.

But to answer your orginial question: I tried to submit an app that had a webview and mobile interface and it didnt get approved.

Answer (score 0):

Max is correct.

It'd be reasonable to assume that the reason you want to turn the Web App into an App Store app has to do with

1. Distribution
2. "Look-and-feel"

It should be noted that while you won't be able to get quite the distribution you would see from the app store, there are some solutions to handle both of those issues, and they kind of dovetail.  Specifically, you can imbue your Web App with special Meta data that causes it to behave differently when an iPhone user bookmarks your app as a Homescreen Bookmark.  This includes doing things like attaching a special icon to use on the homescreen, styling the iPhone's status bar, removing the "browser chrome" like the URL bar, and incorporating a splash screen.  Basically, your app will "look and feel" native because the Browser components will become abstracted out.  Finally, you can augment distribution of your app by placing it on services such as [OpenAppMkt](http://www.openappmkt.com/).

[Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-web-app-meta-tags/) is a decent layman's terms tutorial on how to go about adding iPhone metadata to a web app.

Comment: I guess it'd also be reasonable to assume you want to sell it, but since it's available as a Web App I guessed that particular factor wasn't on your list of priorities.

Comment: This is purely for distribution reasons. We have already tailored it specifically for the iPhone and it looks and feels like an iPhone app.