# How to make a frame of my web application for iPhone and for Android?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, web-applications, html5-video

In addition to this [Can I 'frame' a web-app in an iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096380/can-i-frame-a-web-app-in-an-iphone-app) I see it is impossible to make my `web site` or `web application` a smart phone application. I have two questions:

1. Can I make an iphone application that has an `html 5` page and the login is to my server side which runs `ruby on rails`. sort of a browser that dedicated only to my website or static and constant `URL` ?
2. Can I use a web frame in Android, what module should I use ?

### Basicly:

I want to make smartphone applications to android and iphone which are a frame of `html5` that enables login to my website on some web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what exactly do you want to achieve from your question but I have a feeling that [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)  a.k.a. [Apache Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) might help you with that. It's a software that lets you write mobile applications for iOS, Android, Blackberry, Windows Phone, Palm WebOS, Bada and Symbian in HTML, CSS and Javascript. See the [Getting Started Guides](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html) for a good introduction.

Keep in mind that your app has a good chance of being rejected from the Apple app store if it is just a regular website packaged as an application. If on the other hand your website is a [Web application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) that is already working well in mobile browsers, especially [offline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5), then it may be more natural to use as a native-looking app. (Thanks to [JW.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4321/jw) for pointing it out.)

Comment: I want to make iphone and android apps that are like a browser that connects to a constant URL like www.mysite.com and enables you to  use it as a site but in mask of an app

Comment: So it sounds like PhoneGap/Cordova might help you. See my answer above.

Comment: FYI, Apple has rejected some apps that just load a remote web site into a web view. You may not be able to get this into the app store.

Comment: @JW. I know that Apple has rejected [a lot of apps for countless reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approval_of_iOS_apps). I was answering what I assume to be a technical question whether it is possible to develop a mobile app using entirely Web technology, which it is. Of course you have no guarantee of your app ever being accepted but it can be just like [quite a few](http://phonegap.com/app) have already been.

Comment: I'm not criticizing your answer -- I use PhoneGap myself. Just wanted to give the OP a heads-up. PhoneGap is better suited to apps where most of the code is built into the app itself, in JavaScript.

Comment: I see, I might have misunderstood what you meant. That is a good point. I'll add it to my answer. Thanks.